# Matplotlib - Arrows to and from points along cardinal directions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

**Problem:**
I have an array `terrain` of shape `(N+2,N+2,4)`. In the last dimension, we have either 1's or -1's, -1 if the arrow in that direction is pointing TO the point in question and 1 if the arrow points FROM the point in that direction. The order is north, south, east, west. So, `1,-1,1,1` would correspond to:

[image]

The code I'm trying to work with is the following. But that doesn't work since they are all plotted FROM the point. I couldn't find a way to easily plot from or to the point in the desired direction based on the value of the position in `terrain[i,j]` that corresponds to the direction in question.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N=3
terrain = np.zeros((N+2,N+2,4))

for i in range(1, N+1):
    for j in range(1, N+1):
        terrain[i,j] = np.random.choice([-1,1],4)

for i in range(N+2):
    for j in range(N+2):
        iterr.append([i,j])

iterr = np.array(iterr)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.quiver(iterr[:,0], iterr[:,1], terrain[:,:,0].reshape(((N+2)**2,1)), np.zeros(((N+2)**2,1)), color='k')
plt.quiver(iterr[:,0], iterr[:,1], terrain[:,:,1].reshape(((N+2)**2,1)), np.zeros(((N+2)**2,1)), color='yellow')
plt.quiver(iterr[:,0], iterr[:,1], np.zeros(((N+2)**2,1)), terrain[:,:,2].reshape(((N+2)**2,1)), color='blue')
plt.quiver(iterr[:,0], iterr[:,1], np.zeros(((N+2)**2,1)), terrain[:,:,3].reshape(((N+2)**2,1)), color='red')
```

Comment: Can you change your code to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: I believe now it should be clearer what ``terrain`` is like, which I guess was the problem. Hopefully it's clear that the problem is with the plotting aspect of it.

Comment: The code is still not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There are several issues before the `plt.quiver` calls. What libraries are imported? The `return terrain` doesn't make sense in this context. The `iterr =` line has problems. `itertools` probably is a the library, which method of this library do you want to use? What is the value of `N`? The chance of getting an answer from the stackoverflow community about the _plotting aspect_ will be better if all of the code before `plt.quiver` works as expected.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I already understood the minimal reproducible example thing, but I was missing the second part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [`plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V, C, **kw)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html) is not the easiest method to use in your case. The quiver method will **always** plot an arrow vector (u,v) **from** (x,y).

It is probably easier to iterate over the data and use [`plt.arrow(x, y, dx, dy, **kwargs)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html) to draw the arrows.

Using your data structures and `plt.arrow` I wrote this, where I skipped all the 0 values in `terrain`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N=3
terrain = np.zeros((N+2,N+2,4))

for i in range(1, N+1):
    for j in range(1, N+1):
        terrain[i,j] = np.random.choice([-1,1],4)

iterr = []
for i in range(N+2):
    for j in range(N+2):
        iterr.append([i,j])

iterr = np.array(iterr)

#-------------------------------------------------

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

X = iterr[:,0]
Y = iterr[:,1]
cardinal_vectors = [(0,1), (0,-1), (1,0), (-1,0)]   # north, south, east, west
cardinal_colors  = ['black', 'green', 'blue', 'red'] 

# plot all points        
plt.plot(X,Y,'k.')

for x, y, arrow_directions in zip(X, Y, terrain.reshape(((N+2)**2,4))):

    for direction, vector, color in zip(arrow_directions, 
                                        cardinal_vectors, 
                                        cardinal_colors):

        arrow_size = 0.5
        head_size  = 0.2
        arrow_args = {'length_includes_head' : True,
                      'head_width'           : head_size, 
                      'head_length'          : head_size, 
                      'width'                : 0.02,
                      'fc'                   : color, 
                      'ec'                   : color}

        dx = vector[0] * arrow_size
        dy = vector[1] * arrow_size 

        if direction == 1:
            # arrow FROM (x,y)
            plt.arrow(x, y, dx, dy, **arrow_args)
        if direction == -1:
            # arrow TO (x,y)
            plt.arrow(x + dx, y + dy, -dx, -dy, **arrow_args)

plt.show()
```